# Custom Central Admin page - access denied

Tags: 2010, central-administration, application-pages

I created a custom application page which is deployed to the web applications section in central admin, following this guide:

[How to: Deploy an Application Page to Central Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798467.aspx)

I am a farm administrator. I have access to everything in central admin, but when I try to access my custom page, I get the "Access Denied" error page. I have no idea why it is doing this.  It works on my local machine, but when I deploy to my company's staging environment, I get access denied. SharePoint 2010 by the way.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you check the event viewer and the sharepoint log?

Comment: Is the custom page pretty much blank apart from a label with a Hello World type message on it, like the example? If not I would use some System.Diagnostic.Trace.WriteLine calls to output messages and the capture them using DebugTrace tool just to see if you can find out where the access denied is occuring.

Comment: Als you are a Farm Administrator in Central Administration?

Comment: thanks this got me thinking. I commented out everything from the page_load event and the page now loads. Now i have to figure out what in there is causing the problem. All I am doing is looping through all webapps, site cols, and sites and printing out their URLs to the screen

Comment: It turns out it was failing when I tried to get the web applications from SPWebService. All I needed was to wrap that piece in a 'RunWithElevatedPrivileges' block.